# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Blog#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making in Ruby on Rails app like one from official guide. I created model Post, I made form_for in app/views/new.html.erb like this

```
<%= form_for :blog, url: blog_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    #some other stuff
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

but Im reciving error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Blog#new

Showing <some folders>/hello_world/app/views/blog/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blog"} missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #1):
<%= form_for :blog, url: blog_path do |f| %>
```

I do not know why is this happening, bacause of my routes looks correctly for me. My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :blog
end
```

This is my blog_controller:

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

i added

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

but it did not help

The error isn't showing when i remove url attribute from form_for ("url: blog_path"), but obviously its not working because or form target. I have some other files in project, but i think they are not important for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your new method code in controller as follows

```
def new
  @blog = Blog.new
end
```

and then change your form as follows

```
<%= form_for @blog, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    #some other stuff
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

or simply you can create an object in the form itself

```
<%= form_for Blog.new do, url: {action: "create"} |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    #some other stuff
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It helped partically. I had error no longer, but my post_params private mothod causes error. I copied code from working blog application, but still im reciving an error, so i deleted project and created new.